# Is there a way to save pre-calculated Voronoi diagrams with incremental option to a file?

Tags: python, scipy, geometry, spatial, voronoi

I am trying to save a result of Voronoi diagram that allow incremental point adding. The Voronoi diagram is compiled with around 10<sup>6</sup> points in 2D. I'd like to save the result to file for future use as I see a bit costly to reconstruct the diagram every time I use.

The operation that I would like to perform on this prepared geometry is to add a single point and recalculate the Voronoi diagram, and that's why the incremental option is used below. Because the prepared geometry will be reused many time, I am now looking for a way to store the geometry as a file.

My first attempt is with `scipy.spatial.Voronoi` and `pickle` and hope to unpickle the pre-calculated result in the future.

```
# Assume 'points' is a numpy array of shape (1234567, 2)
vor = Voronoi(points, incremental=True)
with open(outPickle, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(vor, f)
```

And this is what I encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "stringsource", line 2, in scipy.spatial._qhull._Qhull.__reduce_cython__
TypeError: self._qh cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling
```

I also tried `import dill as pickle` but it does not work either.

Comment: See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16190; it wouldn't hurt to add your experience to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to [serialize] ?

No.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/main/scipy/spatial/

The [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/21278e8/scipy/spatial/_qhull.pyx#L2484)
calls into compiled C code.
There is no `dict` of symbols for dill to conveniently iterate over.

The [QHull](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/spatial/_qhull.pyx)
docs *do* suggest a starting point for you:
http://www.qhull.org/road/road-faq/xml/xml-faq.xml#XmlSerializer

You might prefer to work on creating in-memory clones,
as that would also satisfy your use case.

---

The incremental `_update` produces these outputs:

```
        (
            self.vertices,
            self.ridge_points,
            self.ridge_vertices,
            self.regions,
            self.point_region,
        ) = qhull.get_voronoi_diagram()
```

They are easily serialized python containers.
But that doesn't seem to help your use case much.

---

It is a property of Voronoi diagrams that adding a single
point will have strictly local effects on just a tiny
fraction of the million-point diagram.
So ordering your {original, incremental} data
on at least one axis would suggest a way to
solve much simpler sub-problems, involving
only nearby neighbors.

If your use case mostly cares about just the finite
cells on the interior, then selecting points within
a ball of radius K would be the way to go.
If you're willing to put the points in a
[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#build-indexes)
table, then you'll have scalable performant
radius queries available.